# Windows Boot Partition keeps changing

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, partitioning, bcd

Situation:

The system reserve partition keeps getting the drive letter C:\ on a reboot and the C:\ becomes D:\ causing the Windows 7 machine to not boot up. If I go in and manually change drive letters and reset the boot config, I can have Windows boot up.

I've wiped the entire /boot dir and bcd config and rebuilt it manually but the issue kept happening.

This is the 2nd machine this month I've seen happen to.

Ideas on how to fix this or what is causing it?

Comment: First be sure your antivirus is up to date. Second, if your disks are using an MBR partition table (likely) ensure only the real C is marked as "active". It's a stupid legacy bit.

Comment: So the System Reserve should not be marked as an Active partition when working with MBR?

Answer (score 0):

Performing a clean install would help. You can also try running startup repair for at least 2 to 3 times to ensure that faulty or damaged system files has been replaced.

Hope this will work out for you.